# Can we just create one side of a one to many associaciton in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

From my readings for a one to many relation we need a `has_many` on the parent side and a `belongs_to` on the child side. I was wondering does rails create errors or something if I am just interested in one part of the relation and just for example declare the `belongs_to` side in my model ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no errors,

`has_many` and `belongs_to` just auto generate association methods on the class they are called on.

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# works
User.first.posts

# error, method undefined 
Post.first.user
```